# Extract sub-object using keys and create array with keys not unused with javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need extract sub-object from `state` object using `fields` array, witch contains keys that I want extract.

And after, I need an Array with unused keys.

**My input object**

```
state = {id: '123', number: '456', extra_field: 'value'}
fields = ["id", "number", "identifier"]
```

**Wanted results**

```
missing_fields = ['identifier']
data = {id: '123', number: '456'}
```

I'm using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), if is util!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select an object with specific keys, use [_.pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick):

```
const data = _.pick(state, fields);
```

To find missing keys, use [_.difference](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) of state keys from fields:

```
const missing = _.difference(fields, _.keys(state));
```